# What is the L_* macro in busybox?

Tags: c, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, busybox

I am trying to cross-compile busybox but I am getting 'undefined reference' at the linking stage.  Using `nm`, the symbol were in fact missing from the library file (libbb.a in my case.)  Looking into the source ('busybox/libbb/xfuncs.c'), there are all these `#ifdef L_`<function_name> wrapping around the functions in question.  Does anyone know what these macros are?  I grep through the source and cannot find where they are defined.

Comment: which version of busybox ? I checked 1.10, 1.13 and 1.17 and could not find L_ macros, at least in the file you mentionned

Answer (score 1):

These macros are used as sentinels for local versions of a function if the libc does not provide them. In many packages, the autoconf scripts are supposed to detect their presence and set the options in `config.h` accordingly so that the source files can know which should and shouldn't be defined.

Comment: I see... but some of those functions are things like bb_xstrdup and bb_strlen, which I assume are busybox specific so libc would not have those functions would it?